# In PHP is there any benefit to setting a $_POST value to a variable

Tags: php, variables, post

In PHP is there any benefit to setting a $_POST value to a variable versus just using the $_POST value in-line after it has already been sanitised?

Comment: Technically it's fine if it's been sanitized. But still considered bad practice. If you write code that accesses `$_POST` directly, how does that code know for sure if it's been sanitized or not? Better to sanitize `$_POST` variables and store the sanitized values in local variables, then use those.

Comment: When you change the keys of the $_POST array, you have to only change it once in your code instead of every occurance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise is flawed at the point where you "sanitise" the `$_POST` array itself.

1. "Sanitisation" (I'm unable to write that without quotes) is a troubling concept, because it typically boils down to randomly removing characters which are feared have some special meaning in some context. The problem with that is that a) randomly removing data leaves you with some random subset of what your users actually input, never knowing what exactly is gone now, and b) that every context has its own special characters, which means it's virtually impossible to sanitise for all contexts equally.

   You need to *escape* or *encode* specifically for each context individually (HTML-encode for HTML, SQL-escape for SQL **(better: use parameterised queries)**, JSON-encode for JSON etc.). Don't randomly remove a subset of the data in hopes that it will now be "safe" for whatever context you want.
2. Because of 1., mangling all the input data once and discarding the original data means you're really completely discarding the original data. That can be very troubling later on...

Solution:

1. Conceptually, when you produce an **altered version** of a piece of data, assign it to a new variable:

   ```
   $htmlEncodedUsername = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
   $sqlEscapedUsername = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   ```
2. Do this intelligently, don't assign to a thousand new variables:

   ```
   $stmt->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);

   ...

   <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']); ?></p>
   ```

   No need to do either of the things you originally proposed.